# PostgreSQL obtener código

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, data, pgadmin

me estoy adentrando a esto del mundo de las bases de datos, resulta que necesito obtener el código fuente de la base de datos, es decir, un texto que pueda copiar y pegar en un archivo en word de todas las líneas de código que he ido agregando a la DB, estoy usando el SGBD pgadmin. Sin más que decir, un saludo.

Comment: La [documentación](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/import_export_data.html) de la herramienta que indicas (pgAdmin) explica cómo hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando abras el cmd, podrás escribir la siguiente linia:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres nombre_base_de_datos > fichero_de_salida.sql
```

En este video puedes ver lo que te comento: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QR4ugGNT_yI

Salu2